# What is the status of rdmanifests?

Tags: ros, rosdep, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pylon_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/pylon_camera) package [installation procedure](http://wiki.ros.org/pylon_camera#Installation) instructs users to add a custom source to their local `rosdep` (`15-pylon_camera.list`) containing two `source::uri` elements that point to a single `rdmanifest` file: [pylon_sdk.rdmanifest](https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera/blob/ced4d4fb1b1a68877eddb2e8b6be8590dad606ec/rosdep/pylon_sdk.rdmanifest). That `rdmanifest` then is used to make `rosdep` satisfy the `libpylon(-dev)` dependency (when used with `rosdep install ..`).

I can still remember the time when the main `rosdep` database included snippets of `bash` (or even things coming close to full scripts), package-local yaml files with similar lines and `rdmanifest` files being distributed with packages. I also remember a major cleanup of `rosdep` to remove all that (because of running arbitrary snippets of shell script with super-user permissions, `rosdep` silently changing a system's configuration (by adding `ppa`s or other `apt` repositories fi), and because it was just generally not maintainable nor scalable).

Seeing a recently created package like `pylon_camera` use something like `rdmanifest`s makes me wonder what the official status is of those particular pieces of the `rosdep` infrastructure, and whether current users / packagers / maintainers should be discouraged from relying on them?

Afaik the buildfarm will also not build packages that rely on this (deprecated?) functionality, so perhaps that is deterrent enough already, but an authoritative answer would be nice to have.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255238/what-is-the-status-of-rdmanifests?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
Note: I did not choose `pylon_camera` for any reason other than that it is a good example of a current use of `rdmanifest` files.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-21**:
#q251248 is an example of a question about `rdmanifests` that was posted as recent as 2017-01-04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rdmanifests are defined here: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0112.html

They are a tool that works for developers who are installing from source on more exotic platforms. But it's an important tool for users not on our main supported platforms.

They are not recommended for significant distribution and sharing. And cannot be used in a released package.

We don't expect to put a lot of energy into adding features. But because there are use cases where it is valuable and there's no viable alternative, we have not chosen to deprecate it.

My recommendation is that rdmanifests should only be used as a last resort if there are no other options.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thanks. Personally I don't like shell scripts run with super user access installing all sorts of things circumventing the platform's pkg manager, but I can understand why in some cases there might be no other way to do deployment.